# gradle build failed with exception

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, maven-central

[image]

```
apply plugin: 'java'

group 'com.CustomWIH'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'org.jbpm:jbpm-kie-services:7.20.0.Final'
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName='jbpmTutorial'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

jbpm dependency has a dependency that is no longer available in maven repository

org.freemarker version 2.3.26 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker

C:\Users\kona\IdeaProjects\com-CustomWIH>gradle fatJar --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\kona\IdeaProjects\com-CustomWIH\build.gradle' line: 21
- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':fatJar'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compile'.
  >   Could not find org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.26.jbossorg-1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.26.jbossorg-1/freemarker-2.3.26.jbossorg-1.pom
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.26.jbossorg-1/freemarker-2.3.26.jbossorg-1.jar
  >     Required by:
  >      project : > org.jbpm:jbpm-kie-services:7.20.0.Final

I've never ran into this issue before. What do I do in this situation?

Comment: I really dobt this has ever been published to maven central. You need to add the redhat repository: https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dependency tree contains this transitive dependency: `org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.26.jbossorg-1`, which is not found in Maven Central.
The reason it does not exist in Maven Central is that it is not the normal version of freemarker, but a JBoss patched version, which can be seen from the version of the dependency `2.3.26.jbossorg-1`.

Googling for `org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.26.jbossorg-1` took me to this Maven repository: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/

The solution would be to add this Maven repository to your build.gradle like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/"
        // OR this one, as suggested by jb-nizet
        // url "https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/"
    }
}
```